# Getting Input/Output error when running any pip or conda command

Tags: linux, pip, conda

I am trying to access a conda virtual environment, but any conda command gives:

```sh
$ conda env list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/s2/scr/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/s2/scr/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 149, in main
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

pip commands give:

```sh
$ pip list
bash: /s2/scr/miniconda3/bin/pip: Input/output error
```

python seems to be working fine.

Googling this issue seems to indicate a potential disk issue. 
Trying the following suggestion:
[input/output error” when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)
lead to the warning

```sh
$ fsck -c /s2
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
/dev/sdb1 is mounted.


WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.
```

I am trying to run something remotely and don't have permission to access the messages suggested here:
[Every command line I try shows the Input/output error](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49505)

Comment: Ask the system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, I had to remove my `anaconda3` folder completely and download anaconda3 again.

Comment: Removing my `.tox` folder resolved this issue while running tests in Docker by mounting my app folder.